# Does std::multimap::emplace overwrite old keys?

Tags: c++, multimap

```
std::multimap<int,std::string> mymap;
mymap.emplace(1, "hello ");
mymap.emplace(1, "world!");
std::cout << mymap.size() << "\n";
```

Will this echo 1 or 2? I.e., can I use emplace to add new pairs to a multimap, without affecting older pairs with the same key?

Comment: The [documentation for `std::multimap::emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/emplace) seems pretty clear on its course of action. The opening sentence, "Inserts a new element into the container constructed in-place with the given args" leaves little to the imagination, and differs from that of [`std::map::emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) in the lack of any prior-element qualifier.

Comment: Moreover, question - what will `cout` produce?, when you can easily check it yourself, is quite strange...

Answer (score 0):

By trial on http://cpp.sh/ this outputs 2, emplace does not overwrite old pairs with the same key.

Answer (score 0):

Best to check on your own. From definition `std::multimap` allowes to have same key for different values, `std::map` doesn't. Output is: `2`, so it's allowed to have 2 different values under same key in multimap.

IdeONE: https://ideone.com/eRkBmV

Answer (score 0):

From **[associative.reqmts]/4** (emphasis mine):

> An associative container supports unique keys if it may contain at most one element for each key. Otherwise, it supports equivalent keys. The set and map classes support unique keys; **the multiset and multimap classes support equivalent keys**. For multiset and multimap, insert, emplace, and erase preserve the relative ordering of equivalent elements

In fact the whole point of `multimap` is to be able to store multiple elements with the same key, as opposed to `map`.

Comment: I think the question results from misunderstanding what `emplace` means in this case. I think OP doesn't realize that `emplace` is really `insert` but with C++11 semantics.